# Delete Off-Topic Tags

Tags: discussion, tags

When I went through the tags list, I came over with some off-topic tags, like: cooking, computer, etc. Should mods go around and delete the off-topic tags please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They aren't off-topic.  If we have lots of questions about English used in cooking, then I don't see anything wrong with a [cooking](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cooking) tag.  Likewise for [computers](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computers).

Honestly, they're more useful than [grammar](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammar).

Comment: A [tag:not-grammar] tag would have fewer items, but be less useful. Actually, I'm not so sure about that :P Grammar is just far too broad, and yet, if we removed it, I think many people wouldn't know what to tag their questions.

Comment: +1: domain tags like cooking or computers can indicate that the question involves specific jargon. And the grammar tag is quite vacuous and overused.

Comment: Ok, sure. Whatever you say.